# When the minimization of a sum is equal to the sum of the minimization?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, optimization, convex-optimization

I would like to know when is allowed to exchange a $\min$ operator with a summation of certain function. For example, supposing to have a function of two variables $f(x,y)$:

$\min_x \sum_{k=1}^{K} \inf_y |y| + 1/2 (a_k^{T}x-b_k-y)^{2} $

When can I write $\min_x \sum_{k=1}^{K} \inf_y =\min_x  \inf_y  \sum_{k} $   ?

Thank you.

Comment: What is $k$? What is $\Sigma_k$? How does $f$ enter into the final expression?

Comment: I edited the question explicitly writing a function

Comment: I still don't understand the question. In fact, my three original questions are still unanswered. Well, ok, the first is answerred, the last two are not.

Comment: @5xum The summation is over $k$, that indexes the row of a matrix $A \in \Bbb R^{mxn}$, and $f(x,y)$ is what follows

Comment: The expression $\min_x \sum_{k=1}^{K} \inf_y$ is, to me, nonsensical. It doesn't mean anything. What is $x$? Where is $f$? Why are we minimizing over $x$, if $x$ is a variable? Please, provide clear, coherent definitions.